# MySQL Query to Find the Root Element

Tags: mysql

NOTE: This is actually a database of a forum.

I am stuck in an Interesting problem. I created a database with the following fields

```
ID (primary), 
Data, 
ParentID
```

**ParentID** is the **ID** of some other row in the same table. However, this parent child relationship can extend upto few levels. The topmost elements has **0** as **parentID**.

The database is quite large (500 MB), and querying everytime for the root element for a row will be too time consuming. What I want to do here is, add another column ***rootID***. So if a particular data is 3 levels deep, it should have the ID of root (0 level) element in this column.

Can anyone help me out with the query syntax here?

Comment: I don't get it - are you looking for a query to find the root element of a thread to populate the new column? If you can get that in a single query, why bother with the column?

Comment: Not a single query. But any other work around. I am asking this coz' till date I have worked with simple SQL queries only. And reading the documentation is not taking me anywhere.

Comment: Ok, so what language are you using? It would probably be easiest to do this sort of thing in Java or PHP or something where you can keep track of the children as you work up the tree, just recursively getting the parent then setting its is into `rootID` on the way back down the children.

Comment: @josh.trow Yes I know PHP. But won't it be too resource intensive? I am trying it though :). Thanks !

Comment: Aggarway: I'm assuming this won't be run again after you add this column - any new posts should be inserted with the rootID set - you have to be in a thread to post in it don't you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume that root elements have `ID = RootID`. Since adding the root IDs is a one-off thing, I'd just start out with

```
UPDATE `table` SET RootID = ID
```

(after creating the new column, of course) and then run something like

```
UPDATE `table` t1 JOIN `table` t2 ON t1.RootID = t2.ID
   SET t1.RootID = t2.ParentID
 WHERE t2.ParentID <> 0
```

repeatedly until you see zero rows updated. (And later when you add a new row, you just set RootID to that of the parent, if it has one, or to itself -- you don't need to ascend to the root).

Comment: Thanks @LHMatheis. But I am still trying to understand this logic. :|

Answer (score 0):

Use a stored function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION FindRootID(in_ID INT)
RETURNS int(11)
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT ''
BEGIN

DECLARE LastID INT DEFAULT in_ID;
DECLARE ParentID INT DEFAULT -1;

WHILE ParentID != 0 DO
    SET ParentID = (SELECT Parent FROM SomeTable WHERE ID = LastID);
    IF ParentID != 0 THEN
        SET LastID = ParentID;
    END IF;
END WHILE;

RETURN LastID;

END
```

Then:

```
UPDATE SomeTable SET RootID = FindRootID(ID);
```

Comment: Thanks @maclema. But above one proved simpler to me ! :)